# django for loop in a .html template page (newbie)

Tags: django, for-loop

The thing I really hate when learning a new language / framework is how ignorant I feel when I get stuck on a seemingly easy to solve issue.

I have a django for loop inside a html page but for some reason it is not working. I have missed something and cannot fix the issue on my own, so I turn to StackOverflow to help me.

This is my model I am running my query on **models.py**:

```
class RIAchievement(models.Model):
  riAchievementID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="RIAchievementID")
  userLanguageVersionID = models.ForeignKey(UserLanguageVersion, db_column="UserLanguageVersionID")
  typeAchievementID = models.ForeignKey(TypeAchievement, db_column="TypeAchievementID")
  riAchievementTypeUserDescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, db_column="RIAchievementTypeUserDescription")
  riAchievementDescription = models.TextField(max_length=2000, db_column="RIAchievementDescription")
  auth_user_id = models.ForeignKey(auth_user, db_column="auth_user_id")
  class Meta:
    db_table="RIAchievement"
```

This is where my **models.py** file is located in my project: GlobalXpy\app_data\models.py

This is the code within my **views.py** file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from GlobalXpy.app_data.models import RIAchievement

def index(request):
  ri_achievement = RIAchievement.objects.all()
  get_template = loader.get_template('ri_achievement.html')
  return render_to_response(get_template)
```

This is the for loop that is inside my template file (**ri_achievement.html**):

```
{% for e in ri_achievement %}
  <td> Preview  Edit  Duplicate  Delete </td>
  <td> FlagPath </td>
  <td> AchievementType / RIAchievementTypeUserDescription </td>
  <td> {{ e.riAchievementDescription }} </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify in what way it is not working.  Is it that you navigate to the page, but then you see different output from what you expected?

Comment: Where the for loop should display the output, no data is displayed. The for loop is not being undertaken.

Comment: First print the `ri_achievement` in template before for loop. Check it contains data or not?

Comment: to print the ri_achievement, do I simply write:
 <td> {{ ri_achievement }} </td>

if so, this prints / displays nothing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from GlobalXpy.app_data.models import RIAchievement

def index(request):
  ri_achievement = RIAchievement.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'ri_achievement.html',{'ri_achievement': ri_achievement})
```

In your template:

```
{% if ri_achievement %}
   There are {{ ri_achievement|length }} records:
   {% for e in ri_achievement %}
      <td> Preview  Edit  Duplicate  Delete </td>
      <td> FlagPath </td>
      <td> AchievementType / RIAchievementTypeUserDescription </td>
      <td> {{ e.riAchievementDescription }} </td>
   {% endfor %}
{% else %}
   There are no records in the system
{% endif %}
```

Comment: burhan, thanks for the advice. I get the message that there are no records in the system (even though there are 10 records that should be displayed). What should I check to confirm that the code is calling the module / database correctly?

Comment: If you are getting "There are no records in the system", then the code is working correctly. Start a django shell `manage.py shell`, then `from GlobalXpy.app_data.models import RIAchievement` followed by `RIAchievement.objects.all().count()` - what does that print?

Comment: That prints 10 - the number of records in the database.

Comment: Burhan, thanks for the solution. This did not immediately work for me. So I deleted my project and database and installed a fresh installation of my django project & database / models file, which then worked.

I did not find the issue that caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to pass the variable.

```
return render_to_response(get_template, {'ri_achievement': ri_achievement})
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the for loop does not execute (no data is displayed).