# FOR loop over a Django model in a JS script

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-models

I just started a web app using Django and HTML/Javascript templates.

My Django `spot` app contains a `Spot` model that is sent to a HTML template - to be used with the Google Map Api. I've encountered a problem when looping over the variable `spots` containing `Spot.objects.all()`. 
It seems the problem comes from the way I send the data to the HMTL file.

---

----------------------------------------- `Spot` Django-app : models.py --------------------------------------------

```
class Spot(models.Model):
     idn = models.IntegerField(unique = True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
     longitude = models.FloatField()
     latitude = models.FloatField()
```

------------------------------------------------- HTML / JS -----------------------------------------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var IDs = []
   var names = []
   var lat = []
   var lng = []

   { % for spot in spots % }
      IDS.push( {{spot.idn}} );       
      names.push( {{spot.name}} );
      lat.push( {{spot.latitude}} );
      lng.push( {{spot.longitude}} );
   { % endfor % }
```

Then, the lists do not contain any data that can be used afterwards. Worse, the HTML file does not work if the `names.push( {{spot.name}} )` is un-commented.

----------------------------------------- `Spot` Django-app : views.py --------------------------------------------

```
from spots.models import Spot
def index(request):
   return render(request, 'index.html', {'spots':Spot.objects.all()})
```

---

Thanks to the other stackoverflow questions (listed below), I also tried to serialize the `Spot.objects.all()` either with `django.core.serializers.serialize("json", Spot.objects.all() )` or by creating my own serializer (thanks to Django_REST). The problem remains the same. So is the problem in the way I parse my data with JS?

I've look the following link :

- [Returning JSON array from a Django view to a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592811/returning-json-array-from-a-django-view-to-a-template)
- [django for loop in a .html template page (newbie)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326159/django-for-loop-in-a-html-template-page-newbie)
- [Django FOR LOOP in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333824/django-for-loop-in-javascript)

with no success. So if the answer is included or related to these topics, would you mind explaining me something I've been working around for days ...

**EDIT:**
The problem was plural:

- Serializing the data (or not ; I did not for now but everyone who answered agreed to say that it's better to)
- Adding the quotes from `{{ spot.name }}` to `'{{ spot.name }}'`, only to non Integer/Float models (i.e. only the `models.CharFields` fields)
- Google Maps Api may return errors for some (longitude, latitude) tuples even if they are well-defined

Comment: You need to better describe what you mean by "the lists do not contain any data that can be used afterwards". What exactly do you get? You can add a console.log to see what you are getting from the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will not recognize those template tags because you have spaces between the brace and the percent. So, there is no looping being done at all. You need to write them in the correct format:

```
{% for spot in spots %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

Once you do that, you'll start getting all sorts of JS syntax errors because you have not wrapped any of your data in quotes. But, as the comments say, doing this as JSON would be much better.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, my code does not include these spaces - I added them thinking it would be clearer.
And adding the missing quotes to `{{ spot.name }}` didn't help either. What would be the way to do it with serialization?

Answer (score 1):

Even that I think that serializing your data into Json is much better idea. Your javascript code does not work because e.g. `{{ spot.name }}` will render raw string so for javascript to understand it you need to put it in quotes (and of course semicolon after each line).

```
names.push('{{spot.name}}');
```

Comment: As I mentionned it in my edit, it worked by doing it only with the `models.CharField` field, not the `models.IntegerField` and `models.FloatField` (`spot.idn`,`spot.latitude`,`spot.longitude`). Is it "normal', I mean should I force my float and interger values to be strings when read and then turn them into float with JS functions?

Comment: The point here is that in template, Django is rendering values so you are losing types. For example by using [USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#use-thousand-separator) you may get float numbers in format not recognized by javasacript functions. etc. therefore it's better to serialize it to json, because json is javascript's format. JSON = javascript object notation