# Render list of lists elements in django html

Tags: django

I have list of lists like this in django view:

```
res = [['Adam','334','Ford'],['Steve','130','Porsche'],['Dave','510','Ford']]
```

I want to display for example Adam, 334, Ford in table cells

```
{% for n in data %}

    {% for k in n %}

<table style="border:1px solid black;margin-top:15px;width:100%">

    <tr>

        <td style="width:33%;border:1px solid black;">
            {{ k.0 }}
        </td>

        <td style="width:33%;border:1px solid black">
            {{ k.1 }}
        </td>

        <td style="width:33%;border:1px solid black">
            {{ k.2 }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
```

Type of res is list and printing `res[0][2]` - gives Ford, but in table I get - `k.0 = A k.1 = d k.2 = a` 
With one for loop I get triple printing of `res[0]` in k.0/1/2

**UPDATE**

```
span = 3 # making list from every 3 elements

info = full_word.split("|") 

print_info = ["|".join(info[i:i + span]) for i in range(0, len(info), span)]

str_list = list(filter(None, print_info))

 res = []

        for el in str_list:
                sub = el.split('|')
                res.append(sub)

full_word - is a string like: Adam|334|ford|Steve|130|Porsche|Dave|510|Ford|
```

Type - list. Printing `{{ n }}` in html gives 3 lists separated by comma.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326159/django-for-loop-in-a-html-template-page-newbie

Comment: Nice one sandeep, printing only {{ k }} - prints row by row, not separated in cells, but I believe It's matter of wrapping

Comment: can you try `{% for n in data %}<td>{{ n.0 }}</td><td>{{ n.1 }}</td><td>{{ n.2 }}</td>{%endfor%}`

Comment: I mean that under one loop. It tripples every line because of n.0/1/2. And printing only n.0 gives only first element of every list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you

```
<table style="border:1px solid black;margin-top:15px;width:100%">
{% for n in data %}
    <tr>
    {% for k in n %}
        <td style="width:33%;border:1px solid black;">{{ k }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
{% for n in data %}
    {% for first, second, third in n %}
        <td>{{ first }}</td>
        <td>{{ second }}</td>
        <td>{{ third }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: **Need 3 values to unpack in for loop; got 9.** It counts every element of every list. I think it should work, but I'm missing something

Comment: @Victoria I think the `res` is not holding what you expect it to, please include the code that's generating this `res` so that we can find out what's wrong.

Comment: You either want `{% for element in n %} <td> {{element}} </td> {% endfor %}`, or no second for-loop and `<td>{{n.0}}</td><td>{{n.1}}</td>...` The first handles sub-lists that vary in length, the second will "work" if the explicitly indexed elements do not exist by rendering a null string.